# Why does UnhandledExceptionEventArgs.Exception return useful info only on first access?

Tags: uwp, unhandled-exception

In **App.UnhandledException** when accessing e.Exception the first time it returns the message and stack trace as expected. When accessing it again it only returns the message "Exception of type 'System.Exception' was thrown."

Is this a bug or what is going on here?

Example:

```
Private Sub App_UnhandledException(sender As Object, e As UnhandledExceptionEventArgs) Handles Me.UnhandledException
  Dim ex1 = e.Exception
  Debug.WriteLine($"ex1={ex1}")
  Dim ex2 = e.Exception
  Debug.WriteLine($"ex2={ex2}")
End Sub
```

Throwing New MyCustomException($"Testing app crash.") results in:

```
ex1=ErrorHandlingDemo.MyCustomException: Testing app crash. 
   at ErrorHandlingDemo.MainPage.btnForceUnhandledEx_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   at Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.UnhandledError.Propagate()
   at ...

ex2=System.Exception: Exception of type 'System.Exception' was thrown.
```

I am aware the e.Message does hold the original message (and in debug builds a part of the stack trace).
Still the behavior of e.Exception returning valuable information on first access only seems weird.

As a workaround I assign it to a local variable first and use this subsequently.

```
Dim ex = e.Exception
Trace(ex)
If Typeof(ex) is MyCustomException
...
```

Even with this workaround one has to be careful: setting a breakpoint before the assignment (which causes to debugger to access e.Exception) destroys the original value.

See [sample code.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/b71nso3wg5r2bwo/UnhandledExceptionBug.7z?dl=0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very confusing behavior especially because even simply setting breakpoints destroys the original values of UnhandledExceptionEventArgs.Exception. MS should change this behavior or at least document it.

With the workaround of assigning ex.Exception to a local variable the following exception details are available:
[image: Unhandled exception infos debug vs release mode]

For further ideas about handling unexpected exceptions in UWP-Apps my blog post [Global Error Handling for UWP-Apps](https://petermeinl.wordpress.com/2016/07/09/global-error-handling-for-uwp-apps/) might be helpful.